# drop shadow framed environment using mdframed & tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed, shadows

I'm attempting to make a `drop shadow` environment using `mdframed` and `tikz`. So far, I have (perhaps naively) tried

```
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={fill=green!20,drop shadow}]{myshadowbox}
```

I know that shadow-boxes can be made using `fancybox` and `ntheorem` with `PSTricks`, but I'm particularly interested in seeing a solution using `mdframed` and `tikz`.

The MWE below produces a framed environment, and with the `rounded corners` you can see a shadow has been drawn (in the bottom right corner, look carefully!), but I can't seem to move it- I've tried passing options to `drop shadow` such as `shadow xshift=-5ex` but with no success.

So, how can I add and customize a `drop shadow` when using a `newmdenv`?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newmdenv[tikzsetting={fill=green!20,drop shadow},
                roundcorner=10pt ]{myshadowbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{myshadowbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myshadowbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The shadow is there, just hard to see. I was sure the solution was to add `shadow={shadow xshift=1.0ex, shadow yshift=-0.2em}` to make the shadow more obvious but that does not appear to be sufficient.  If you include `opacity=1` with the shadow options that makes it more easier to see that it is there.

Comment: This seems produce a shadow but I feel you should be able to do better: `\newmdenv[
 tikzsetting={
  fill=green!20,
  drop shadow={
    shadow xshift=1.0ex, 
    shadow yshift=-0.5em,
    fill=black!50, 
    opacity=1,
    every shadow
  } 
 },
 roundcorner=10pt, 
 outerlinewidth=3.0pt 
]{myshadowbox}`

Comment: @PeterGrill Agreed! Yes, you'll see in my screen shot, the shadow *is* there ,but it's not very pronounced :)

Comment: @cmhughes: I use the function `clip` to get the correct width of the frame. This was the easiest way to handle three lines. I provided the command `\mdfcreateextratikz` (not documented yet) which can be redefined inside the key `settings`. At the moment I can create any example. Tomorrow I have LateX to build such one.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Ok, great! Thanks for the explanation! Glad I didn't miss anything in the documentation (which is excellent) :) Thanks for such a great package

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Completely EDIT 2012-03-04:**

I uploaded the new version 1.3 to CTAN. At the moment the files are available at [github](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed).

This version provides a key named `shadow`. This allows to draw a shadow. The shadow can be manipulated by the new keys `shadowsize` and `shadowcolor`

If you use `framemethod=tikz` it is important to load the TikZ library `shadows`.

<sub>`mdframed` can  do the job but I don't want to load any libraries.</sub>

For the methods TikZ and PSTricks I defined a style `mdfshadow` by `tikzset` / `newpsstyle`. For more settings manipulate this key.

Based of the new modification I created the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={fill=green!20},
          roundcorner=10pt,shadow=true]{myshadowbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{myshadowbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myshadowbox}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{myshadowbox}
\lipsum
\end{myshadowbox}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

An other example is provided in file `mdframed-example-pstricks.pdf` which uses `pstricks` and `frametitle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=pstricks]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[%
          shadow=true,
          shadowsize=11pt,
          linewidth=8pt,
          frametitlerule=true,
          roundcorner=10pt,
          ]{myshadowbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{myshadowbox}[frametitle={Der Beweis}]
\lipsum[2]
\end{myshadowbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! This works really well! I'll leave it the question active for a few more hours, and will accept later on :) What's the best way to know when you have updated the package on ctan? Thanks again, and thanks for such a great, user-friendly package :)

Comment: I just tried it with a page break- it looses the shadow. I actually kind of like that feature though- did you intend it?

Comment: @cmhughes: Please see my edit

Comment: I guess `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}` is supposed to be there just once, not twice?

Comment: This is great, thanks so much :) Is the new version available on `ctan` as well? I've never worked with `github` before.

Comment: @cmhughes: Please wait few minutes. Then I upload a new version to github. After this I will upload the new version to CTAN. After this I will edit my answer. (PS: created options: `shadowsize`, `shadowcolor` ;-)

Comment: Ok, will do :) Really nice work, I can't wait to study the documentation and play with it!

Comment: @cmhughes: Done