# Enclosing a float into a shadowed box

Tags: floats, boxes

I have created a float enivoirment as shown below

```
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{example}{thp}{lop}[section]
\floatname{example}{Example}
```

I would like to enclose the example in the a shadowbox, including its caption and numbering and also provide a coloured background. Example is provided below.

```
----------------------------------------------
| Example 2.3: How to define an attribute    |
|                                            | 
| def ..etc                                  |
|                                            |
----------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas

Comment: Perhaps the post on [Rounded corner colored box around figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/rounded-corner-colored-box-around-figure) might be a good start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can use the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/rounded-corner-colored-box-around-figure) that Wener points out. Also, you will need to use and [install](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed) the new version of the `mdframed` as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43207/drop-shadow-framed-environment-using-mdframed-tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}% needed for the shadows

% Styles
\mdfdefinestyle{shadowBox}{backgroundcolor=yellow!10,shadow=true, roundcorner=25pt,tikzsetting={draw=yellow!80!black!30, line width=1pt}}%

\mdfdefinestyle{blueBox}{backgroundcolor=blue!10,shadow=true, shadowcolor=blue!10, roundcorner=25pt,tikzsetting={draw=blue!80!black!30, line width=1pt}}%

\makeatletter
  % General command that defines the mdframed
  \newcommand\shadowFloat[1]{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{\begin{mdframed}[style=#1]}%
  \def\@fs@mid{}%
  \def\@fs@post{\end{mdframed}}\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
  % Link the style with the frame, giving it a name
  \newcommand\fs@yellowFloat{\shadowFloat{shadowBox}}
  \newcommand\fs@blueFloat{\shadowFloat{blueBox}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\floatstyle{yellowFloat}
\restylefloat{figure}% bind the style to the figure
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \rule{100pt}{150pt}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\floatstyle{blueFloat}
\restylefloat{figure}% bind the style to the figure
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \rule{100pt}{150pt}
    \caption{Another caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: shades]

Comment: Perfect! Is it possible to have different styles for different floats. In my book, i have floats of different type, 'Examples', 'Logs', 'code snippets', etc

Comment: Yes you can, see my update.

Comment: Thanks! One more (last one) question, the frames seem to go beyond my page margins, any way to fix this!

Comment: @user739807: Really? Only the shadows run into the margin. I explained that in the documentation.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, I removed the shadows to test, Still the frames go beyond the margin. I wanted to attach an example (an image) here, but i cant find instructions on how to do so!

Comment: @user739807: send me an email. Please with a small minimal example.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, I have the example, but i can't find your email on this site! Let me know how to send you the example.

Comment: @user739807: I am the author of mdframed. My email is also there. marco.daniel at mana-nada.de