# tikz and mdframed + shadow drop and shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed, shading, shadows

I'm interesting in [Boxed text between pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115576/boxed-text-between-pages/115605#115605) 2nd version: exercise box with mdframed.
Ho to add to this :
 Vertically shaded frametitle and Vertically shaded box with dropping shadow?

Yes i have seen several examples here for shadows and vertical shading but thay use styles i cannot put in mdframed.

here is another example.
2 questions:
1.ho can i change size of rounded titlebox shadow's size?
2. how can i remove that red titlebox thing? or another alternative would be to start shading from top including rectangular titleframe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{exe}

\newenvironment{Fancybox}[1][.5\textwidth]
{%
    \stepcounter{exe}%
  \mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
      \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=8pt]
      \node[draw=blue!40,anchor=east,rectangle, thick,font=\color{black}, double,
       top color=blue!40,
                    bottom color=blue!5,
                    rounded corners=8pt,
                    drop shadow,
                    ]
        {\strut Exercise~\theexe};},%
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    innertopmargin=1pt,
    apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={top color=blue!40, bottom color=white}}},
    linecolor=blue,%
    innerlinewidth=1pt,
    topline=true,
    shadow=true,
    rightline=true,innerleftmargin=10,innerrightmargin=10,
    frametitlerule=false,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=red,
    shadowcolor=blue!40,
    frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=blue!40,font=\color{black}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1) {$\clubsuit$};}
  }
  \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=#1]\allowdisplaybreaks\relax%
}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{Fancybox}[1\textwidth]
         \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}
\begin{Fancybox}[1\textwidth]
         \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I know there are several solutions for shadows and shading, but I need it with mdframed theorems for exercises and solutions splitted across pages. I guess i nedd 'addextra' commands to add exercise points on frame title, right?

Comment: You can just add your comment to your OP.

Comment: have you seen [drop shadow framed environment using mdframed & tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43207)

Comment: yes, see example . I updated post

Comment: i needed different frame title..  It is almost working, but shadow is displayed only on one page..and i need this to work with theorems

Comment: You are overriding the shadow. Comment out the lines `outerlinewidth=1em` and  `outerlinecolor=white` and you'll see the required shadow. Why are you using those options?

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina thanks..that worked...I was playng with some examples posted :)..how can i change shadow color?

Comment: Use the `shadowcolor` key, adding to the options something like `shadowcolor=red,`.

Comment: updated example code with suggestions and with new question :)

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili I've provided an answer below. Sorry to bother you, but I noticed that even you have up-voted answers to your questions, you still haven't accepted any answers (voting and accepting are two different actions). Please consider (after a sensible wait) to accept the answers that you think best solved your problems; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: sorry, did not give attention the fact that comments also can be voted :)

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili I wasn't talking about voting comments (although you can do that as well), I was talking about accepting answers (by clicking on the checkmark to their left). Please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option using `singleextra`, `firstextra` to place the title, instead of `frametitle`; in this way you can easily obtain the desired shading effect for the background. To control the shadow attributes, you can use all the available keys for example `scale`, `xshift`, `yshift` (refer to the PGF manual). For frames without page breaks a decoration was added midways vertically on the right side (as requested in a comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcounter{exe}

\newenvironment{Fancybox}[1][\textwidth]
{\stepcounter{exe}%
  \mdfsetup{
      singleextra={%
      \node[draw=blue!40,anchor=east,rectangle, thick,font=\color{black}, double,
       top color=blue!40,
                    bottom color=blue!5,
                    rounded corners=8pt,
                    drop shadow={shadow xshift=1.5pt, shadow yshift=-1.5pt},anchor=west
] at ([xshift=20pt]O|-P)
        {\strut Example~\theexe};
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=blue!40,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1) {$\clubsuit$};},%
      firstextra={%
      \node[draw=blue!40,anchor=east,rectangle, thick,font=\color{black}, double,
       top color=blue!40,
                    bottom color=blue!5,
                    rounded corners=8pt,
                    drop shadow={shadow xshift=1.5pt, shadow yshift=-1.5pt},anchor=west
] at ([xshift=20pt]O|-P)
        {\strut Example~\theexe};},%
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    innertopmargin=18pt,
    linecolor=red,%
    innerlinewidth=0.8pt,
    topline=true,
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={%
shade,top color=blue!35, bottom color=white}}},
    frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    linecolor=blue,%
    innerlinewidth=1pt,
    topline=true,
    shadow=true,
    rightline=true,innerleftmargin=10,innerrightmargin=10,
    shadowcolor=blue!40,
  }
  \begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=#1]\relax%
}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Fancybox}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\begin{Fancybox}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\begin{Fancybox}[7cm]
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{Fancybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much..and one more how cen i get middle of mdframed box (Y coordinate), i'm trying to put some extra staff on Y like here ' singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=red,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1) {$\clubsuit$};}
' calculation does not work on my case
 

Heres' one possible solution; the Fancybox" http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115576/boxed-text-between-pages/115605#115605

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili and what should happen if the box has a page break? In the solution I proposed in the question you linked, no decoration is shown in this case (and as I said there, this seems a sensible choice). Do you agree with this? I mean, no decoration if a page break occurs?

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili please see my updated answer showing how to add the decoration.

Comment: yes i know, i have seen, when box continues to another page there is no '$\clubsuit$' on 'fancytitle box' it is ok...I made this optional..i have added new mdf key to pass code to display in middle of box (similar to exercise points example , which is in documentation of mdframed). Just dont know how to get in middle of box :) ...I have to update original question or post modified code as new unswer..This is not convenient..i can not post lagre code in comments

Comment: can i post mu updated code as answer? I did this one time and it was deleted :)

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili It would be better to edit your question and add the new code there, indicating what you need and what you have tried.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: In the new version you can work with the node `mdframe.east` ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Ah, that's helpful. I still haven't had the time to look the new version; will do it as soon as I can.

Comment: I still think it woud be great to have option just use titlebox true/false option (see my original 1st post), than so many redefinitions and so on can be avoided. right?