# Fading shadow with mdframed

Tags: mdframed, shadows

I would like to create an environment like this:

[image: Box with fading shadow]

which I have created with this code:

```
%
% Boxed environment with semi-transparent shadow.
%
\newlength{\boxw}
\newlength{\boxh}
\newlength{\shadowsize}
\newlength{\boxroundness}
\newlength{\tmpa}
\newsavebox{\shadowblockbox}

\setlength{\shadowsize}{6pt}
\setlength{\boxroundness}{3pt}

\newenvironment{shadowblock}[1]%
{\begin{lrbox}{\shadowblockbox}\begin{minipage}{#1}}%
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\settowidth{\boxw}{\usebox{\shadowblockbox}}%
\settodepth{\tmpa}{\usebox{\shadowblockbox}}%
\settoheight{\boxh}{\usebox{\shadowblockbox}}%
\addtolength{\boxh}{\tmpa}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\addtolength{\boxw}{\boxroundness * 2}
\addtolength{\boxh}{\boxroundness * 2}

\foreach \x in {0,.05,...,1}
{
\setlength{\tmpa}{\shadowsize * \real{\x}}
\fill[xshift=\shadowsize - 1pt,yshift=-\shadowsize + 
1pt,black,opacity=.04,rounded corners=\boxroundness] 
(\tmpa, \tmpa) rectangle +(\boxw - \tmpa - \tmpa, \boxh - \tmpa - 
\tmpa);
}

\filldraw[fill=yellow!50, draw=black!50, rounded corners=\boxroundness] (0, 
0) rectangle (\boxw, \boxh);
\draw node[xshift=\boxroundness,yshift=\boxroundness,inner sep=0pt,outer 
sep=0pt,anchor=south west] (0,0) {\usebox{\shadowblockbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

As you can see if you compile it has a fading shadow, however, as it uses `\minipage` in case the text is very long it doesn't split into 2 pages. I have though that this could be achieved with the environment `mdframed`, however, although it has shadows it doesn't have any fading effect. I have tried for example:

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!50,linecolor=black!50,roundcorner=10pt, % shadow=true,
     tikzsetting={shade,
      top color=yellow!50,
      bottom color=yellow!10,
      rounded corners=1pt,
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5,shadow blur extra rounding=1.3pt,shadow yshift=-0.5cm}
      }]
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{mdframed}
```

but when you compile it doesn't correcty draw the shadow:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: have you seen [drop shadow framed environment using mdframed & tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43207)

Answer (score 7):

#### Update:

The default shadows produced either with `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` don't produce the desired effect if the frame splits; however, both packages are powerful enough to admit easy solutions.

Here's one possible solution using `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[
backgroundcolor=yellow!60,
roundcorner=4ptem,
middleextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue] 
    (P) --
    ([xshift=\sshift pt]P) -- 
    ([xshift=\sshift pt]P|-O) --
    (P|-O) -- cycle;
  }
},
secondextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([xshift=\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P|-O)
    {[sharp corners] -- ([xshift=\sshift]P) -- 
    (P)} -- 
    (P|-O) -- ([xshift=\sshift]O);
  }
},
firstextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([yshift=-\sshift]P) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P) 
    {[sharp corners] -- ([xshift=\sshift]P|-O) -- 
    (P|-O)} -- ([yshift=-\sshift]P);
  }
},
singleextra={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([xshift=\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P|-O) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]P) -- +(-6pt,0) --
    (P) -- 
    (P|-O) -- ([xshift=\sshift]O);
  }
},
]{mymdbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{mymdbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mymdbox}
\begin{mymdbox}
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]
\end{mymdbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's one possible solution using `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mytcbox}{
breakable,
enhanced,
colback=yellow!60,
overlay middle={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue] 
    (frame.north east) --
    ([xshift=\sshift pt]frame.north east) -- 
    ([xshift=\sshift pt]frame.south east) --
    (frame.south east) -- cycle;
  }
},
overlay last={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([xshift=\sshift]frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]frame.south east)
    {[sharp corners] -- ([xshift=\sshift]frame.north east) -- 
    (frame.north east)} -- 
    (frame.south east) -- ([xshift=\sshift]frame.south west);
  }
},
overlay first={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([yshift=-\sshift]frame.north east) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]frame.north east) 
    {[sharp corners] -- ([xshift=\sshift]frame.south east) -- 
    (frame.south east)} -- ([yshift=-\sshift]frame.north east);
  }
},
overlay unbroken={
\foreach \sshift/\svalue in {6/gray!10,5/gray!20,4/gray!30,3/gray!40,2/gray!50,1/gray!60}
  {
  \fill[\svalue,rounded corners] 
    ([xshift=\sshift]frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]frame.south east) --
    ([xshift=\sshift,yshift=-\sshift]frame.north east) -- +(-8pt,0) --
    (frame.north east) -- 
    (frame.south east) -- ([xshift=\sshift]frame.south west);
  }
},
before={\vskip1em},
after={\vskip1em},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytcbox}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mytcbox}

\begin{mytcbox}
\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\end{mytcbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's a detail you hadn't caught. When mdframe splits a frame, in 2 pages for example, in the new page the  box will not start with the rounded corners, and in the previous page the box will not finish with rounded corners. That is to note that there aren't 2 boxes but one that is splited. It's better understood in the documentation http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf#page=3 in section 3 "The frames" (page 3)
But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Álvaro I am familiar with the documentation of `mdframed`. Perhaps you could have a look to the documentation of `tcolorbox` in search for a similar functionality.

Comment: @Álvaro I am doing some changes to the original code to produce the effect you want if the frame splits; as soon as it's ready I'll let you know.

Comment: Gracias, al final llegué a una solución como puedes ver en el post que acabo de publicar ^^

Comment: @Álvaro en todo caso, he puesto una versión mejorada (aún hay detallitos que pulir), pero las sombras se interrumpen apropiadamente si el marco se parte. In any case, I've updated my answer with an improved version (some details can sill be improven) in which the shadows are interrupted at the proper locations when the frame splits.

Comment: @Álvaro agregué otra solución, usando ahora `mdframed`. I added another solution using `mdframed` this time.

Comment: It looks very well although in the corner it's not properly drawn, although being a minor detail.

Comment: Anyway, could you recommend me a guide where to find information about the commands you inserted? Like the ones related with the coordinates O, P P|-O. I'm a beginner in Tikz but I find it a very powerful tool

Comment: @Álvaro `O` and `P` are special coordinates set internally by `mdframed`; `P` is the top right corner of the frame and `O` is the bottom left corner (I believe they are not explicitly documented, but they appear in the examples of the `mdframed` documentation and in the package code). `P|-O` is using the perpendicular coordinate system of TikZ (this is documented in the PGF manual).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. La verdad es que ponerme a redactar mi proyecto fin de carrera con LaTeX, la primera vez que redactaba algo serio y extenso con este lenguaje, ha sido muy arduo al principio, e incluso después de meses redactando sigo viendo que hay infinidad de cosas que me quedan por aprender.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gonzalo Medida's previous answer I have arrived to a good solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows} % for pgf-umlsd
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{myboxdos}{
    breakable,enhanced,
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    colback=yellow!50,
    %skin=freelance, % esto "estropea" los bordes cuando se divide un colorbox
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    before=\vspace{1em},
    after=\vspace{1em},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myboxdos}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{myboxdos}

\end{document}
```

The problem with his answer was the missing "enhanced" attribute and that it should not write "skin=XXX" as that overwrites the "enhanced" skin.

And about the shadow, instead of writing individual shadows the "fuzzy" option does that and with the "drop" it automatically places in the righ place.

Besides I have added some extra space before and after the box.

This is the final version:
[image]